# Redirecting to a specific wizard step

Tags: jquery-steps

Am redirecting to a specific step in the wizard after clicking a button from another page. Where do I need to set it up from?

This is to enable a user to click f from another page so that it directs them to a chosen step on the wizard.

I want when the user selects or clicks a certain option from another page. They are redirected to a chosen step from the step wizard. But I am now out of ideas. Any help or lead info thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go into the plugin's js file find the setStep function and replace:

```
$.fn.steps.setStep = function (step)
{
  throw new Error("Not yet implemented!");
};
```

with:

```
 $.fn.steps.setStep = function (step)
 {

 var options = getOptions(this),
    state = getState(this);

return _goToStep(this, options, state, step);

};
```

Then in your js file

```
$('#yourForm').steps("setStep", 0);
```